# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 in Xcode 8.3.2 iOS Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, command, bin

I have some problem with my framework that added to my project.
I got this error :

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

So i search in stack and fixed it formulator and any devices but when try to on Generic iOS Device get this error again.
Please help me to fix this.
Failed to read file or folder at

> /Users/mymac/Projects/myprojectname/Carthage/Build/iOS/OneSignal.framework
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1